# Refactoring Long and Too Many Branches Methods for Rubocop

Tags: ruby, rubocop

*I provided an update below to some findings...*

Here's a method I have in my current code:

```
def query(data_set, conditions)
  query_data_set = data_set.dup
  search_conditions = parse_conditions(conditions)

  search_conditions.each do |condition|
    if condition.class == Array
      condition.each do |term|
        if term.class == Symbol
          query_data_set = entity.send term, query_data_set
        else
          query_data_set = search_data_text(query_data_set, term)
        end
      end
    end

    if condition.class == Hash
      condition.each do |key, value|
        query_data_set = method("query_#{key}").call(data_set, value)
      end
    end
  end

  query_data_set
end
```

Rubocop hates this for three reasons:

```
C: Assignment Branch Condition size for query is too high. [17.03/15]
  def query(data_set, conditions)

C: Method has too many lines. [19/7]
  def query(data_set, conditions)

C: Use next to skip iteration.
  search_conditions.each do |condition|
```

I don't EVER want to skip an iteration so I'm not sure why I would use `next` at all. There is never a case where skipping an iteration would make sense for this bit of code.

So going to the other complaints, you'll see at that the top of this method I have already broken out one action (the call to `parse_conditions`). There's also a call to `search_data_text`. My only point here being I have tried to be modular where it seemed to make sense.

Even if I move that large `search_conditions.each` block to a separate method, Rubocop is going to complain that my new method is too long as well. Which I suppose means adding yet a *third* method that my *second* method will call? That seems odd to me. Or perhaps it means I have to not branch so much, I guess. But why is the branching bad? Even if I switch to some other structure (like a case...when), I'm still branching. And I do need to test those conditions because handling is different for a nested array, an array with a symbol, or a hash.

I'm trying to build up my intuition for being able to look at problems like this and figure out an effective and efficient solution .... but it seems what I end up doing is being terribly inefficient and ineffective *with my time*. That tradeoff is worrying me given that I can't see why my code is bad.

Anyone mind taking a stab at this and helping me see how I can get the above method into a state that maintains some semblance of readability but that fits into the style guidelines that Rubyists prefer?

**----------------------**
**UPDATE**
**----------------------**

About the best I could come up with is this:

```
def query(data_set, conditions)
  query_data_set = data_set.dup
  parse_conditions(conditions).each do |condition|
    query_data_set = check_conditions(condition, query_data_set)
  end
  query_data_set
end

def check_conditions(condition, data)
  if condition.class == Array
    condition.each do |term|
      data = entity.send term, data if term.class == Symbol
      data = search_data_text(data, term) unless term.class == Symbol
    end
  end

  if condition.class == Hash
    condition.each do |key, value|
      data = method("query_#{key}").call(data, value)
    end
  end
  data
end
```

That `check_conditions` method is still too long for Rubocop and still has too high of a branch condition size.

As far as I can see, and nowhere I've checked has been able to show me different, the only thing that can be done would be to perhaps make methods out of the checks for array and hash. In other words, each `if` condition in `check_conditions` would get its own method. But that seems needlessly silly to me. I'm basically breaking up logic, passing variables to different methods, just so that I can keep my method count below some arbitrary value.

This feels way wrong to me as a way to do design. But I don't see a way to change my logic such that it still accomplishes what it needs to but does so under seven lines per method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a way to do it. It may not be the cleanest but nothing else was working. Here's what I did:

```
def query(data_set, conditions)
  query_data_set = data_set.dup
  parse_conditions(conditions).each do |condition|
    query_data_set = check_conditions(condition, query_data_set)
  end
  query_data_set
end

def check_conditions(condition, data)
  data = process_condition_array(condition, data) if condition.class == Array
  data = process_condition_hash(condition, data) if condition.class == Hash
  data
end

def process_condition_array(condition, data)
  condition.each do |term|
    data = entity.send term, data if term.class == Symbol
    data = search_data_text(data, term) unless term.class == Symbol
  end
  data
end

def process_condition_hash(condition, data)
  condition.each do |key, value|
    data = method("query_#{key}").call(data, value)
  end
  data
end
```

So I had one method that I thought was reasonable, albeit admittedly a bit wordy. But everything was in one place. This has now become four methods where, as a reader of the code, you have to trace the variables through those methods. I guess that's progress. :-/

Interestingly, after *all* this, my entire class is now considered too long by Rubocop. *Sigh.* Anyway, living with that particular arbitrary style is at least more palatable than living with the other arbitrary styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
def query(data_set, conditions)
  data_set = data_set.dup
  parse_conditions(conditions).each do |condition|
    condition.each do |e|
      case e
      when Array  then method("query_#{e.first}").call(data_set, e.last)
      when Symbol then entity.send(e, data_set)
      else             search_data_text(data_set, e)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is pretty nice and compressed. Unfortunately, if I do that it looks like the right data isn't being passed back. (My original query_data_set variable.) So code that expects that now fails. Still, though, you have given me something to at least investigate and I appreciate that.

Comment: The only difference regarding that is that the duplicated `data_set` is passed instead of the original one to the first argument of the `method` method, which should not alter the behaviour.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what's going on then. The code that actually calls that `query()` method is this: `results = @rolodex.query(@data.data_set, conditions)`. With your code, that `results` variable contains `[["Jurassic"]]`. With my original code it contains a hash: `{"Abrictosaurus"=>#<Dinosaur:0x007faa938717a8 @name="Abrictosaurus", @period="Jurassic", ...` So the return value is definitely different.

Comment: I think I see what it is. In my original code, I have an iteration `search_conditions.each do |condition|`. Within that, I check if the `condition.class` is an Array. If it is, then I have *another* iterator. That's the difference I think between your and my code. The Symbol will only be checked once I'm sure I have an Array. It's also critical that there's a Hash check. I think you gave me a good idea of how to start; I just need to figure out how to situate the conditions. Whether those pass a Rubocop check is whole other matter! :)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on your own answer, I would maybe suggest some functional goodness... (i.e., `Enumerable.inject` plus `lambda` A.K.A. first order functions).

(Note that I did not question or change the logic of your own code; I simply transformed it mechanically).

```
def query(data_set, conditions)
  parse_conditions(conditions).inject(data_set) do |data_set, condition|
    check_conditions(condition, data_set)
  end
end

processors = {
  'Array' => lambda do |condition, data|
               condition.inject(data) do |data,term|
                 term.class == Symbol ? entity.send(term, data)
                                      : search_data_text(data, term) 
               end
             end,
  'Hash' => lambda do |condition, data|
               condition.to_a.inject(data) do |data, pair|
                 method("query_#{pair[0]}").call(data, pair[1])
               end
             end
}

def check_conditions(condition, data)
  processors[condition.class.name].call(condition, data)
end
```

A few less lines of code (inconsequential), and the explicit if/else control structures plus explicit "data = " and "return data" parts are gone. Everything is very explicit now, and the chance for obscure little errors is less.

Of course, only do things like that if you are working in a team that knows/likes the functional style; some folks dig it, others hate it.

If you were not working on `Hash` and `Array`, I would likely suggest to use OO instead of the functions (i.e., distribute the two processing methods into their respective classes). Technically possible by re-opening Hash and Array; certainly not advisable though.